# cannot open browser for tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am running the `mnist_wiht_summaries` and running the tensorboard pointing to the same log dir. It seems like the tensorboard is running successfully it shows:

```
Starting TensorBoard 47 at http://0.0.0.0:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

but when I open `http:/0.0.0.0:6006` it indicates

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "" The Web Server may be down, too
>   busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to
>   requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

Comment: what happens when you try to access via http://localhost:6006 ?

Comment: thanks that is what I just did :) and it wored

Comment: Glad this worked. I've put it as an answer to your question so it can be marked as the answer to your issue. Thanks

Comment: http:/0.0.0.0:6006  => there is a slash missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is often resolved by using http://localhost:6006

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue myself several times. What you can do is access your computer at its external IP address.

Simply run `ipconfig` (windows) or `ifconfig` (linux) to find the ip adress, and then open your browser at that adress, e.g. `10.153.82.75:6006`.

In some cases, it also seems that accessing `localhost:6006` works.

Comment: Using an external ip is not really the best way to go about this as it involves going through your router which in some cases may have port restrictions, port forwarding etc. With multiple computers on the network you may also run into some problems (although unlikely providing port setup is correct.) You might aswell bypass the external networking hardware. It's an unnecessary step!

Comment: For me `localhost` has not always worked, but this has. But I agree, if `localhost` works, you should use it.

Comment: strange that localhost doesn't work for you. Perhaps you have reconfigured your localhost ip on your machine? It's just an internal thing so it should work! At least you've found a way of doing it.

Comment: This is on a server which I'm connecting to over ssh, but even from inside the server localhost did not work. Perhaps I changed something during setup.